# Sitecore lucene: How to index a property as a numeric field to enable range searches

Tags: lucene, sitecore, numeric

Using Sitecore 8.2.1

I have defined a custom index patched into Sitecore's ContentSearch config.  I have defined a computed fields 'MinPrice' and 'MaxPrice within the index.

The fields appear in the index but I would like to query these decimal values for range or use greater than or less than.

I am using the Sitecore PredicateBuilder to create the query.

I have defined the computed fields as:

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">    
   <field fieldName="minprice">
     ~.MinPriceIndexField, <ref_assembly>
   </field>
</fields>
```

And also an entry in the fieldMap as:

```
        <field fieldName="minprice" storageType="YES" indexType="ANALYZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.Decimal" 
            settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"> 
           <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
        </field>
```

I have also tried: 
indexTypes of UN_TOKENIZED, TOKENIZED.
Using System.Double instead of System.Decimal.

From my understanding the Type is determined when the LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration is built using Type.GetType(string type).
Then the LuceneFieldBuilder.CreateField method determines from the Type whether the field should be a NumericField or just a Field.

Using Luke, the fields don't seem to be indexed as Numerics.  When searching with ranges in Luke these are treated as string ranges i.e. minprice:[1 TO 3] would erroneously include 150, 250 etc.  Using the app with predicate builder and using the Between method the indexed values are treated as strings and greater than and less than do not affect the results.

I have also tried defining a field reader for the field as PrecisionNumericFieldReader.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: And what is the code of `MinPriceIndexField` computed index field class?

Comment: It returns the min price (decimal) from aggregation data generated from child items related to the indexed item.  Null could potentially be returned if the aggregation was null.  It inherits AbstractComputedIndexField